# Origin of auto-generated tags

Tags: support, tags, tag-synonyms

I've been taking a look at the [new tags page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags?tab=new), and I've seen two tags with 0 question tagged: [vs](/questions/tagged/vs) and [2012](/questions/tagged/2012). Since nobody has used them on a question, I don't know how they have been created and who did it (I suppose it has something to do with the [visual-studio-2012](/questions/tagged/visual-studio-2012) tag).

What is the purpose of this *auto-generated* tags? By separate, they are not really synonyms of another tag, and I see no point in creating a tag wiki for them.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They're not auto-generated. They *were* created by users, but the questions under them have already had the tag removed. They will be destroyed when the tag cleanup script runs next. You don't need to (and shouldn't) do *anything* with them. Just let them die.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, when I saw they were the only tags on the list that aren't being used, it seemed a bit odd to me, but now I understand what happened.

Comment: Out of interest - How often does the cleanup script run?

Comment: @nickhar: Once a day. I assume around 03:00 UTC with most of the other tag stuff, but who knows. The devs always just say every 24 hours.